# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Administration' or one of its dependencies

Tags: sharepoint-2007

When I want to the access SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration, web page gives the following error:

> An error occurred during the processing of . Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Administration' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I put the `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Administration.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.dll` files to the GAC.

I also tried restarting the IIS and recycling the application pools but it did not work.

Comment: “…during the processing of .” — of what? What does the error message say? Did you inspect ULS logs for *Unexpected* and *Critical* entries? What customizations did you deploy to the SharePoint farm (your own, developed, or third party)? Are you really asking this in the context of some programming problem or is this a general SharePoint server administration question?

Comment: @OndrejTucny I only I want to open the Share Point admin web page http://Myserver:40422. Then I am getting the error.. Error message does not give any detail except this. It only writes during the processing of.

Comment: I am only the end user. I did not make any customization or something else @OndrejTucny

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: OK, then this question is not a good fit for SO. Btw. you shouldn't be adding any SharePoint DLLs to the GAC yourself. The product doesn't expect this and most likely it will break any future updates (in general; SP2007 support ended already).

Comment: @OndrejTucny Does it make any sense ?  Entering function PsconfigApplicationContext.ClosePsconfigApplication
05/14/2018 17:41:14  1  INF      The psconfig ui application is closing
05/14/2018 17:41:14  1  INF      We have do not have a main form, thus the application has been told to close prior to showing the ui at all
05/14/2018 17:41:14  1  INF    Leaving function PsconfigApplicationContext.ClosePsconfigApplication
05/14/2018 17:41:14  1  INF    Return code indicates a success
05/14/2018 17:41:14  1  INF  Leaving function PsconfigUserInterfaceMain.Main